# Listening for an HTTP POST message from windows service

Tags: c#, httprequest

I have a class (installed as a Window Service) that listens to HTTP Requests.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program : System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase
{
    public static String navn = "PM_RequestHandler";
    private bool RunThread = true;

    public void StartMe()
    {
        IPAddress localAddr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(localAddr, 1234); // http://localhost:1234
        server.Start();

        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        String data = null;

        while (RunThread)
        {
            TcpClient client =  server.AcceptTcpClient();
            data = null;

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream(); 
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

            // LOG
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\PM_RequestHandler.txt", true);
            sw.WriteLine(data);
            sw.Close();

            client.Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread thr = new System.Threading.Thread(new
        System.Threading.ThreadStart(this.StartMe));
        thr.Start();
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        RunThread = false;
        base.OnStop();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
    }
}
```

I have a web service I run (locally) to try my previous class. 
I use `SoapUI` to invoke it.
The problem is that the web service uses POST requests and I cannot catch them.

My log is empty and it seems that the class just catches `Get` requests made manually in the browser.
Why is that so?

Comment: If you want to debug your code you can paste it in a console application or attach to the running service process. POST vs GET has no difference, they're just TCP connections and in the http request comes "POST" instead of "GET" (yes yes, it's ultrasimplified, I know) so the problem should be anywhere else. Have you tried to do a POST request from a browser directly to your listener (using something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httprequester/)?

Comment: You don't want to try to implement your own HTTP server (which is what it seems you're trying in a very rudimentary way to do here).  If you're running on Windows, I would strongly recommend you look at using HttpListener, or some other pre-built HTTP protocol handler.

Comment: @CodingGorilla HttpListener works really well also on Linux/MacOS with mono ;)

Comment: I will now try with PostMan for Chrome. I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, it works. The problem was the installed service, that sometimes stops without reason.

Comment: Thanks you ! I just have a problem of encoding viewing the log now. but the main issue is solved. thanks again

Comment: GusMan i have to run it on Windows :(

Comment: I dont know if i can use the same thread, but:
How can i manipulate the request and answer to the call with an XML value ?